# Subform doesn't requery

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a acces Form in which you can select a User with a dropdown
Then i have a subform with all the licenses of that user.
The licenses can be removed from that user with a button.
After a license has ben removed i want to refresh the form, so that it actually disapears.

I think the Form_Dirty Event is the right one to trigger the refresh.
I tried:

```
Private Sub Form_Dirty(Cancel As Integer)
    MsgBox "deleted a license"
End Sub
```

and the box shows up on every deletion. so i know that event fires. perfect.
Buuuut whatever refresh command i put into that function it doesnt refresh.
I tried:

```
    Me.requery
    Me.Recalc
    Me.refresh
    Forms.user.Form.requery
    Forms.user.licenses.Form.requery
```

it just stays the same.
If i press F5 then it refreshes.
How can that be?

Comment: Why don*t you delete from subforms recoordset? Where is the button (sub or parent)?

Comment: Its on the subform.
But its not strictly speaking a deletion rather i set the record to inactiv and then it gets filtered out by the query which is the datasource of the subform...

Comment: Use`Me.Requery`after the update of inactive flag at end of button.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the *AfterUpdate* event of the subform:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    If Me!Active.Value = False Then
        Me.Requery
    End If
End Sub
```

**Edit**. Or:

```
Private Sub Active_AfterUpdate()
    If Me!Active.Value = False Then
        Me.Dirty = False
        Me.Requery
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: at the time of this event the recordsource is not yet updated it takes some time. Since i didn't manage to put a delay I ended up using a timer but with a condition as you suggested:
``` Private Sub Form_Timer()
    On Error GoTo done
        If Me!active.value =False Then
            Me.Recalc
        End If
done:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Uh, a timer should be avoided. Try the _AfterUpdate_ of the checkbox itself.